# Wordpress Thumbnail Sizes Added to End of Images?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm switching themes on my website and the size of the image is added to the end of every image, like so: `http://cdn.site.com/wp-content/uploads/ruzowitzky-192x134.jpeg` the `192x134` is the size of the image, or as an another example `http://cdn.site.com/wp-content/uploads/django-unchained2-600x250.jpg`

the images above are showing up as blank, but when I disable W3TC or remove the size leaving it with `http://cdn.site.com/wp-content/uploads/django-unchained2.jpg` it works fine. What do I do so the new thumbnail sizes will work?

Here are the different sizes I have:

```
//Add Featured Image to Posts
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
  set_post_thumbnail_size( 640, 321, true );
}

//Main Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 192, 134, true );
}

//Post Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 184, 126, true );
}

//Video Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'video-thumb', 286, 151, true );
}

//Slider Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'slider-thumb', 640, 250, true );
}

//Sidebar Thumbnail Size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'sidebar-thumb', 47, 47, true );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Install plugin "[Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)" and go to tools -> Regenrate Thumbnails and then click on the button on the page, it will create the thumbnail sizes which earler were not present on your website.

2) Clear W3TC cache, go to settings and there you will find an option for clearing cache.

Comment: As a sidenote for those who are batch-resizing a large number of images to new image sizes, the plugin [Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) is a good alternative (it might take a while, but it will never time out).